# Are all the norms of $L^p$ space equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Are all the norms of $L^p$ space equivalent? That is, for any $p,~q \in R^+$, there exist two positive number $C_1,~C_2$ such that
$$
C_1\|u\|_{L^q} \le \|u\|_{L^p} \le C_2\|u\|_{L^q}.
$$

Comment: No. Consider $\frac{1}{(1+\lvert x\rvert)^{n/p}}$. It's in $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $q > p$, but not in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If  fact for every $p$ and $q$ there is a function $f$ with $\|f\|_p<\infty$ and $\|f\|_q=\infty$. Using this you can show that for any measure space $X$ (I'm assume your questions is about $L^p(\mathbb{R})$) if there is a $p$ and $q$ with $\|\cdot\|_p$ equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_q$ then they are all equivalent and all the $L^p(X)$ are finite dimensional.